# Ansible hostvars not evaluated in group_vars

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook :

```
- name: Do something
  hosts: myHost
  tasks:
  - debug:
    msg: "{{hostvars[groups['gatewayHost'][0]].ansible_host}}"
  - debug:
    msg: "{{hostvars[item].foo}}"
    with_items: "{{ groups['webapps'] }}"
```

For group webapps I have a groups_vars/webapps.yml :

```
foo: "{{ hostvars[groups['gatewayHost'][0]].ansible_host }}"
```

My issue is that when running the playbook the first debug message is correctly evaluated, but the second debug message just display `hostvars[groups['gatewayHost'][0]].ansible_host` and doesn't evaluate the variable. I guess I'm missing something but I can't see what.

(Note, If I try to evaluate `groups['gatewayHost']`, it's correctly evaluated in both cases, playbook and group_vars)

Answer (score 0):

After digging into Ansible issues, I found this one https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/20545 which is pretty close to my issue.